# Kerberos principal does not have the expected format

Tags: hbase, kerberos, janusgraph

I try to deploy Janus Graph server on my big data platform and it works behind to Kerberos Authentication.

First of all, JanusGraph can access and authenticate with Zookeper successfully.
But there is a problem when it try to connect HBase like below;

```
Connecting to FusionInsight2/172.16.250.11:21302
1751 [hconnection-0x29a0cdb-shared--pool1-t1] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation  - PrivilegedAction as:root (auth:SIMPLE) from:org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:740)
1753 [hconnection-0x29a0cdb-shared--pool1-t1] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.HBaseSaslRpcClient  - Creating SASL GSSAPI client. Server's Kerberos principal name is developuser@HADOOP.COM
1753 [hconnection-0x29a0cdb-shared--pool1-t1] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation  - PrivilegedActionException as:root (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.IOException: Kerberos principal does not have the expected format: developuser@HADOOP.COM
```

According to this log, my principal format is not correct. It waits principal format like `username/hostname@realm`.

But when I execute `klist` command on my server with root user, here is the result;

```
[root@localhost bin]# klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: developuser@HADOOP.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
08/08/2018 16:14:15  08/09/2018 16:14:15  krbtgt/HADOOP.COM@HADOOP.COM
```

My default principal format is different than what it is waited. **So I am confused** about should I use this default principal when I go to HBase.

And this is my configuration file;

```
gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory

#HBASE CONFIGURATIONS
storage.backend=hbase
storage.hostname=host1,host2,host3

storage.hbase.ext.hbase.security.authentication=kerberos
storage.hbase.ext.hbase.regionserver.kerberos.principal=developuser@HADOOP.COM

storage.hbase.ext.hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort=24002
```

**Another interesting point is that**, I can connect HBase shell by using hbase shell command, lets see the console output;

```
[root@localhost bin]# hbase shell
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/client/HBase/hbase/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/client/HDFS/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Debug is  true storeKey false useTicketCache true useKeyTab false doNotPrompt false ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is null refreshKrb5Config is false principal is null tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
Acquire TGT from Cache
Principal is developuser@HADOOP.COM
Commit Succeeded 

Debug is  true storeKey false useTicketCache true useKeyTab false doNotPrompt false ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is null refreshKrb5Config is false principal is null tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
Acquire TGT from Cache
Principal is developuser@HADOOP.COM
Commit Succeeded 

2018-08-09 08:26:27,592 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2018-08-09 08:26:27,606 WARN  [main] shortcircuit.DomainSocketFactory: The short-circuit local reads feature cannot be used because libhadoop cannot be loaded.
INFO: Watching file:/opt/client/HBase/hbase/conf/log4j.properties for changes with interval : 60000
2018-08-09 08:26:28,016 INFO  [main] zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Process identifier=hconnection-0x5b251fb9 connecting to ZooKeeper ensemble=fusioninsight3:24002,fusioninsight2:24002,fusioninsight1:24002
2018-08-09 08:26:28,016 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=fusioninsight3:24002,fusioninsight2:24002,fusioninsight1:24002 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.PendingWatcher@230a73f2
2018-08-09 08:26:28,018 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: zookeeper.request.timeout is not configured. Using default value 120000.
2018-08-09 08:26:28,018 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: zookeeper.client.bind.port.range is not configured.
2018-08-09 08:26:28,018 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: zookeeper.client.bind.address is not configured.
2018-08-09 08:26:28,018 INFO  [main-SendThread(fusioninsight1:24002)] client.FourLetterWordMain: connecting to fusioninsight1 24002
2018-08-09 08:26:28,020 INFO  [main-SendThread(fusioninsight1:24002)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Got server principal from the server and it is zookeeper/hadoop.hadoop.com
2018-08-09 08:26:28,020 INFO  [main-SendThread(fusioninsight1:24002)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Using server principal zookeeper/hadoop.hadoop.com
Debug is  true storeKey false useTicketCache true useKeyTab false doNotPrompt false ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is null refreshKrb5Config is false principal is null tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
Acquire TGT from Cache
Principal is developuser@HADOOP.COM
Commit Succeeded 

2018-08-09 08:26:28,021 INFO  [main-SendThread(fusioninsight1:24002)] zookeeper.Login: successfully logged in.
2018-08-09 08:26:28,021 INFO  [Thread-8] zookeeper.Login: TGT refresh thread started.
2018-08-09 08:26:28,021 INFO  [main-SendThread(fusioninsight1:24002)] client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Client will use GSSAPI as SASL mechanism.
2018-08-09 08:26:28,022 INFO  [Thread-8] zookeeper.Login: TGT valid starting at:        Wed Aug 08 16:14:15 EET 2018
2018-08-09 08:26:28,022 INFO  [Thread-8] zookeeper.Login: TGT expires:                  Thu Aug 09 16:14:15 EET 2018
2018-08-09 08:26:28,022 INFO  [Thread-8] zookeeper.Login: TGT refresh sleeping until: Thu Aug 09 11:27:45 EET 2018
2018-08-09 08:26:28,022 INFO  [main-SendThread(fusioninsight1:24002)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server fusioninsight1/172.16.250.10:24002. Will attempt to SASL-authenticate using Login Context section 'Client'
2018-08-09 08:26:28,023 INFO  [main-SendThread(fusioninsight1:24002)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /172.16.235.1:53950, server: fusioninsight1/172.16.250.10:24002
2018-08-09 08:26:28,024 INFO  [main-SendThread(fusioninsight1:24002)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server fusioninsight1/172.16.250.10:24002, sessionid = 0x1200000a81d68c48, negotiated timeout = 90000
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 1.3.1, rUnknown, Fri May 18 09:54:11 CST 2018

hbase(main):001:0>
```

I also checked **hbase-site.xml** file but there is different principal;

```
<property>
<name>hbase.regionserver.kerberos.principal</name>
<value>hbase/hadoop.hadoop.com@HADOOP.COM</value>
</property>
```

When I use this principal in my configuration file, it throws invalidate credantial exception.

So, do you have any idea or advice to solve this problem? If you have any idea, please share with me.

### **UPDATE 1**

If I change principal with principal of region server, I face this invalid credential exception;

```
1584 [main-SendThread(hadoop.hadoop.com:24002)] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Reading reply sessionid:0x14000537d430a17b, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 5,4  replyHeader:: 5,17180208329,0  request:: '/hbase/meta-region-server,F  response:: #ffffffff0001a726567696f6e7365727665723a32313330327214ffffffc9fffffffa784b69650425546a1bae467573696f6e496e73696768743210ffffffb6ffffffa6118ffffffaaffffffb5ffffffebffffffc5ffffffd12c100183,s{17180136443,17180136443,1533718229066,1533718229066,0,0,0,0,68,0,17180136443} 
1592 [main-SendThread(hadoop.hadoop.com:24002)] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Reading reply sessionid:0x14000537d430a17b, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 6,8  replyHeader:: 6,17180208329,0  request:: '/hbase,F  response:: v{'replication,'meta-region-server,'rs,'splitWAL,'backup-masters,'table-lock,'flush-table-proc,'region-in-transition,'online-snapshot,'acl,'switch,'master,'running,'recovering-regions,'tokenauth,'draining,'namespace,'hbaseid,'table} 
1741 [hconnection-0x29a0cdb-shared--pool1-t1] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.token.AuthenticationTokenSelector  - No matching token found
1742 [hconnection-0x29a0cdb-shared--pool1-t1] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl  - RPC Server Kerberos principal name for service=ClientService is hbase/hadoop.hadoop.com@HADOOP.COM
1742 [hconnection-0x29a0cdb-shared--pool1-t1] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl  - Use KERBEROS authentication for service ClientService, sasl=true
1757 [hconnection-0x29a0cdb-shared--pool1-t1] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl  - Connecting to FusionInsight2/172.16.250.11:21302
1761 [hconnection-0x29a0cdb-shared--pool1-t1] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation  - PrivilegedAction as:root (auth:SIMPLE) from:org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:740)
1763 [hconnection-0x29a0cdb-shared--pool1-t1] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.HBaseSaslRpcClient  - Creating SASL GSSAPI client. Server's Kerberos principal name is hbase/hadoop.hadoop.com@HADOOP.COM
1764 [hconnection-0x29a0cdb-shared--pool1-t1] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation  - PrivilegedActionException as:root (auth:SIMPLE) cause:javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
1765 [hconnection-0x29a0cdb-shared--pool1-t1] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation  - PrivilegedAction as:root (auth:SIMPLE) from:org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.handleSaslConnectionFailure(RpcClientImpl.java:643)
1766 [hconnection-0x29a0cdb-shared--pool1-t1] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl  - Exception encountered while connecting to the server : javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
1766 [hconnection-0x29a0cdb-shared--pool1-t1] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl  - SASL authentication failed. The most likely cause is missing or invalid credentials. Consider 'kinit'.
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.HBaseSaslRpcClient.saslConnect(HBaseSaslRpcClient.java:179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupSaslConnection(RpcClientImpl.java:617)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.access$700(RpcClientImpl.java:162)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:743)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:740)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:740)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.writeRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:906)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.tracedWriteRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:873)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1241)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:227)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:336)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.scan(ClientProtos.java:34094)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.openScanner(ScannerCallable.java:400)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:204)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:210)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:364)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:338)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultBoundedCompletionService$QueueingFuture.run(ResultBoundedCompletionService.java:65)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:147)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:122)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:187)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:224)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:212)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:192)
        ... 26 more
```

Thank you.

Comment: Common sense suggests that  `regionserver.kerberos.principal` is about the principal used by the RegionServer **service**, not about your client principal. The "invalid credential" issue is about something else.

Comment: Dear Scharfrichter, I added more log output to topic. If I change kerberos.principal with regionserver's one, I faced above error which is shared in UPDATE1. Could you please check it also? You may advice some way.